# Agent/MailboxProcessor in C# using new async/await

Tags: c#, f#, agent, c#-to-f#, async-await

*This question combines two topics I don't fully understand*

Reading through a [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/async-padl-revised-v2.pdf) about async in F#, I came across the topic of Agents/MailboxProcessors, which can be used to implement reactive state machines. Could the new async/await functionality in C#5 be used to implement something similar in C#, or is there already something analogue that would be better suited?

Comment: Could you fix the broken link?

Comment: @czifro, ok done.

Answer (score 11):

With a bit of pretty horrible hacking, you can use the `MailboxProcessor` type from C# using `async`. Some difficulties are that the type uses some F# specific features (optional arguments are options, functions are `FSharpFunc` type, etc.)

Technically, the biggest difference is that F# async is dealyed while C# async creates a task that is already running. This means that to construct F# async from C#, you need to write a method that takes `unt -> Task<T>` and creates `Async<T>`. I wrote a [blog post that discusses the difference](http://tomasp.net/articles/async-csharp-differences.aspx).

Anwyay, if you want to experiment, here is some code you can use:

```
static FSharpAsync<T> CreateAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> f)
{ 
  return FSharpAsync.FromContinuations<T>(
    FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<
      Tuple< FSharpFunc<T, Unit>, 
             FSharpFunc<Exception, Unit>,
             FSharpFunc<OperationCanceledException, Unit> >>(conts => {
    f().ContinueWith(task => {
      try { conts.Item1.Invoke(task.Result); }
      catch (Exception e) { conts.Item2.Invoke(e); }
    });
  }));
}

static void MailboxProcessor() {
  var body = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<
                FSharpMailboxProcessor<int>, 
                FSharpAsync<Unit>>(mbox =>
    CreateAsync<Unit>(async () => {
      while (true) {
        var msg = await FSharpAsync.StartAsTask
          ( mbox.Receive(FSharpOption<int>.None), 
            FSharpOption<TaskCreationOptions>.None, 
            FSharpOption<CancellationToken>.None );
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
      }
      return null;
    }));
  var agent = FSharpMailboxProcessor<int>.Start(body,
                FSharpOption<CancellationToken>.None);
  agent.Post(1);
  agent.Post(2);
  agent.Post(3);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As you can see, this looks really horrible :-).

- In principle, it could be possible to write a C# friendly wrapper for the `MailboxProcessor` type (just extract the ugly bits from this code), but there are some problems.
- In F# you often use tail-recursive asyncs to implement the state machine in the mailbox processor. If you write the same thing in C#, you'll eventually get `StackOverflow`, so you'd need to write loops with mutable state.
- It is perfectly possible to write the agent in F# and call it from C#. This is just a matter of exposing C#-friendly interface from F# (using the `Async.StartAsTask` method).

Comment: Ouch, my eyes :) The `Task -> Async<Unit>` was precisely the bit that I got stuck on, so I'll have a look at that. How about rewriting a MailboxProcessor in C#, or would it just not be worth the effort because of your second bullet point about recursion?

Comment: @Benjol - I wrote a similar type in C#. It was about 300 lines of code. The difference being a simplified API.

Comment: @Benjol: I think that rewriting MailboxProcessor in C# would be an option too. It is not easy to get the locking and synchronization right (especially for `TryScan` method), but I think it should work (You can always avoid recursion, but in case of _state machines_ the code looks quite bad, so it is unfortunate if that's what users have to write)

Answer (score 3):

In principle, I expect it would be straightforward to translate these F# APIs into C#-plus-async-await.

In practice, I am unclear if it would come out beautiful, or ugly and full of extra type annotations, or simply un-idiomatic and in need of some API-massaging to make it feel more at home in C#.  I think the jury is out until someone does the work and tries it.  (I presume there is no such sample in the await CTP.)

Comment: Downloaded the CTP. Now I will proceed to expand my ignorance by trying :)

Comment: I see your Super Breakaway made it into the samples, congratulations :)

Comment: Ouch! Too hard for me this stuff :(

Answer (score 0):

You might nave a look at [Stact](https://github.com/phatboyg/Stact). It hasn't been updated in a little while, but if you wanted to make something with a little better C# support, you might find it a good starting point. I don't think it's up-to-date with async/await, though.